# autohotkey script speed & prevent spam click

Tags: windows, autohotkey

**First question is:** Is this script as fast as possible as it can get?

I'm talking about the commands in the start are they necessary/unnecessary? do they help at all when its about simple key remapping?

I would like it to run as fast as possible since I do pretty intense & fast stuff with this script.

**The 2nd question is:** How to prevent this script from spamclicking?

If I keep "E or R" held down, it will spam click which I do not want it to do.

How to fix this?

```
#NoEnv
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 99000000
#HotkeyInterval 99000000
#KeyHistory 0
ListLines Off
Process, Priority, , A
SetBatchLines, -1
SetKeyDelay, -1, -1
SetMouseDelay, -1
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0
SetWinDelay, -1
SetControlDelay, -1
SendMode Input

*e::Click
return

*r::Click
return

Ins::Suspend
return
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to the second question**, add the KeyWait command to your hotkeys, [KeyWait - Syntax & Usage | AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm)

```
*e::
Click
KeyWait, e
return

*r::
Click
KeyWait, r
return
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to the first question**, it looks like you may have gotten the header lines from here: [How to optimize the speed of a script as much as possible](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6413). The post explains each line (see below) and even includes some benchmarks for other things.

In your case, if you're only doing simple key remapping, it's probably not worth including any of these lines with exception to `SendMode , Input`, as that is the most reliable send mode. You mention doing "pretty intense & fast stuff with this script"; what this means exactly will determine if the header lines are necessary.

> Notes
>
> **1.** #NoEnv is recommended for all scripts, it disables environment variables.
>
> **2.** The default #MaxHotkeysPerInterval along with #HotkeyInterval will stop your script by showing message boxes if you have some kind of rapid autofire loop in it. Just put some insane unreachable high number to ignore this limit.
>
> **3.** ListLines and #KeyHistory are functions used to "log your keys". Disable them as they're only useful for debugging purposes.
>
> **4.** Setting an higher priority to a Windows program is supposed to improve its performance. Use AboveNormal/A. If you feel like it's making things worse, comment or remove this line.
>
> **5.** The default SetBatchLines value makes your script sleep 10 milliseconds every line. Make it -1 to not sleep (but remember to include at least one Sleep in your loops, if any!)
>
> **6.** Even though SendInput ignores SetKeyDelay, SetMouseDelay and SetDefaultMouseSpeed, having these delays at -1 improves SendEvent's speed just in case SendInput is not available and falls back to SendEvent.
>
> **7.** SetWinDelay and SetControlDelay may affect performance depending on the script.
>
> **8.** SendInput is the fastest send method. SendEvent (the default one) is 2nd place, SendPlay a far 3rd place (it's the most compatible one though). SendInput does not obey to SetKeyDelay, SetMouseDelay, SetDefaultMouseSpeed; there is no delay between keystrokes in that mode.
>
> **9.** If you're not using any SetTimer, the high precision sleep function is useful when you need millisecond reliability in your scripts. It may be problematic when used with SetTimer in some situations because this sleep method pauses the entire script. To make use of it, here's an example that waits 16,67 milliseconds:
>   `DllCall("Sleep",UInt,16.67)`
>
> **10.** When using PixelSearch to scan a single pixel of a single color variation, don't use the Fast parameter. According to my benchmarks, regular PixelSearch is faster than PixelSearch Fast in that case.
>
> **11.** According to the documentation (this text is found in the setup file), the Unicode x64bit version of AHK is faster, use it when available.